# Git shell errors out

Tags: windows, posh-git

I have both Git Bash and Git Shell.

When I run Git Bash I don't have any issues.

However running Git Shell, I received following:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Identity added: /c/Users/Igor/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/Igor/.ssh/id_rsa)
WARNING: posh-git's profile.example.ps1 will be removed in a future version. To avoid a change in behavior, copy its
contents into your C:\Users\Igor\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.
```

I think this message comes from one of the earlier versions of Git software.

All I want to do right now is to switch to use Git Shell. Its interface is closer to *nix one.

What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: update posh-git, if you still have the message, follow the instructions, or you can inspect the content of said file (`profile.example.ps1`) and see for yourself whether you should keep it or not.

Comment: @LeGEC, what is `posh-git`? I don't have this software on my machine? Is it part of the GIT?

Comment: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git standard Powershell extension for git (mainly brings the decorations in your prompt) -- from the error message, it looks that it was installed at some point on your machine

Answer (score 0):

It comes from [`dahlbyk/posh-git` commit fa7941b](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/commit/fa7941b441eebe89bf5f0607372bd63badfc7784), v0.7.0-pre1, Jan. 2016(!)

Since [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) does not comes with posh-git, it means you have posh-git on your `%PATH%`.

In a simple CMD, as long as you have C:\Program Files\Git\bin in your `%PATH%` (where `bash.exe` is), a simple bash is enough to switch to a bash session.

Comment: this is weird. When I go to Control Panel -> Programs, I see a Git that is installed on 24 January 2022 and its version is 2.3.5. I guess I didn't update it properly? If that's the case - how can I properly update it? Because I have another weird issue with the coloring...

Comment: @Igor Do you have Windows 10 or 11? Because with 11  I do a `winget upgrade git.git`

Comment: @Igor : it is a powershell module, that gets loaded after you add the relevant lines in your profile.ps1 (<- don't remember the exact name on Powershell). Depending on how it got installed (you can manually download the code, and run a script to edit your profile), it may not show up in your system's installed programs.

Comment: @VonC, no usin Wondpws 8.1

Comment: @LeGEC, I didn't change anything after the install.